# How to access lower tabs from a list created using FrameLayout in Android?

Tags: android

I created a list type interface.

[image]

As you can see it consists of different colors, the problem is I'm not able to access the lower items on this(Red part is appearing in half and is not accessible in the above image).

How can I access it?

Below is the code I use(FrameLayout over a vertical LinearLayout):-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/arcade_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="127dp"
        android:background="@drawable/arcade_tab"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:visibility="visible">

    </FrameLayout>

    below comes more FrameLayouts...
</LinearLayout>
```

apart from that I used an XML file too in the drawable folder:-

Like I wanted to create a tab named "adventure", I used "adventure_tab.xml",

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"              android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#3F51B5" />
    <size android:width="390dp" android:height="150dp"/>

</shape>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using non-scrollable layout so it won't scroll or show the view below the visible part. change it to something like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/arcade_frame"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="127dp"
            android:background="@drawable/arcade_tab"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:visibility="visible">

        </FrameLayout>

        <!--below comes more FrameLayouts...-->

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

and yes the recommended way is to use the [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html) for such kind of views.

Comment: The single child view of your `ScrollView` should essentially **always** use a `wrap_content` height or a fixed size, and not `match_parent`.

Answer (score 1):

As you have used multiple framelayouts in a linearlayout, the linearlayout is populated with multiple views and going out of focus from the screen. And as you have not used any scroll view you are not able to scroll the screen to view the rest of the items at the bottom. Therefore there are two possible solutions:

1. **Static:** If you have just limited number of items for your page, then you can use ScrollView as the parent view. Then use a linearLayout inside it. Inside the linearlayout you can then define your chile views, i.e. framelayout items.

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <ScrollView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/arcade_frame"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="127dp"
            android:background="@drawable/arcade_tab"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:visibility="visible">

        </FrameLayout>

        below comes more FrameLayouts...
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

2. **Dynamic:** If you want to dynamically generate the framelayout items, then you can use recyclerview. And then use framelayouts as recyclerview items.
   Click [here](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/) to view details on how to use recyclerview.